# Prove that a product is less than n

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I want to prove that $\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i)^{-a_i} \leq n$ where $a_1+\cdots+a_n=1$. This is related to shannon entropy where each $a_i$ is a probability. I haven't been able to find a reference for this proof. It is obvious that the product is equal to $n$ when $a_1=...=a_n$, nonzero, but I am lost on the less than part.

Comment: I changed your sums to products. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, I wrote this on my phone and it took so long that I ended up making mistakes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $(0,\infty)$, the function $f(x) = x\log x$ satisfies $f''(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, which is positive in this interval. Hence, $f$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$ and

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n f(a_i) \ge f\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

This means

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i\log a_i \ge \frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{1}{n}\right),$$

which implies

$$-\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i\log a_i \le \log n.$$

By exponentiation,

$$\prod_{i = 1}^n a_i^{-a_i} \le n.$$

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that the KL divergence(relative entropy) is always positive. Consider the KL distance between $\underline{a}$ and the uniform distribution.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_i^n a_i \log(\frac{a_i}{1/n}) &\geq 0 \\
\implies \sum_i^n a_i \log(a_i) + \log(n) & \geq 0 \\
\implies -\sum_i^n a_i \log(a_i) \leq \log(n) \\
i.e., \prod_i^n (a_i)^{-a_i} \leq n
\end{split}
\end{equation}